# como solucionar el Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error en Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard?

Tags: php, iis, windows-server

Estoy intentando configurar mi IIS para utilizar PHP seguí todos estos pasos pero una vez que termino me dice

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error.

Este es el link que segui para la configuración: [PHP installation on IIS7, IIS7.5, and IIS8](http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00495/0/PHP-installation-on-IIS7-IIS7.5-and-IIS8.html)

Intento hacer http://localhost/phpinfo.php y me sale la informacion del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacer la prueba de funcionamientos de php, ve a la carpeta `C:\PHP` pero desde la consola (CMD) y escribe php-cgi.exe y presiona enter. Nos dices que aparece.

Comment: VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 no es compatible con esta compilación de PHP vinculada con 14.28

Comment: Solo actualiza la versión de Microsoft Visual C++ y realiza de nuevo la prueba que te comente. Si todo sale bien reinicias IIS y pruebas

Comment: ya instale la ultima version de Visual C++ y sigue el mismo error

Comment: El error de IIS o de PHP?

Comment: solamente veo ese errror que puse en la imagen imagino es de php por lo del cgi, tengo xampp localmente en mi computadora y funciona bien, que pasaria si copio la carpeta php de xampp y la muevo al servidor donde tambien tengo la carpeta php y hago los cambios necesarios en el archivo .ini